# Como gerar uma string de insert a partir de json

Tags: javascript, json, sqlite

Sou novo e javascript e preciso gerar uma string de insert para sqlite com essa string:

```
{ "InputFile" : "PER_02.inp", "RunTime" : 1492167103, "Reservoir" : "5", "Elevation" : 400.000000, "UpStreamId" : "172", "UpStreamP" : 95.000000, "PRU_l_ID" : "143", "PRU_setting" : 32.531769, "downstream_n_ID" : "164", "downstream_p" : 32.531769, "downstream_l_ID" : "9", "main_flow" : 0.600256, "local_flow_set" : 0.000000, "BLEED1_n_ID" : "6", "BLEED1_demand" : 0.000000, "BLEED2_n_ID" : "7", "BLEED2_demand" : 0.000000, "BLEED3_n_ID" : "8", "BLEED3_demand" : 0.000000, "CRIT1_n_ID" : "153", "CRIT1_p" : 97.513428, "CRIT1_p_set" : 25.000000, "CRIT2_n_ID" : "141", "CRIT2_p" : 104.513039, "CRIT2_p_set" : 0.000000, "CRIT3_n_ID" : "162", "CRIT3_p" : 81.419167, "CRIT3_p_set" : 0.000000, "control_type" : 0 }"
```

O campos da tabela tem os mesmos nomes.

Comment: Basicamente, você quer fazer uma travessia nos membros e valores e por algo assim? `INSERT INTO tabela (InputFile, Runtime,...) VALUES ('PER_02.inp', 1492167103, ...)`

Comment: Isso mesmo, valeu..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Levando em consideração que se deseja transformar o JSON em uma query `INSERT` válida no SQLite, temos de atravessar o objeto passado e guardar as chaves e os seus valores. Vou guardar esse valores em dois vetores, `chaves` e `valores`, de tal modo que a `chaves[i]`, quando aplicado ao JSON, retornaria `valores[i]`.

1. iterar sobre o objeto
2. guardar a chave sendo iterada em `chaves`, e o valor dessa chave em `valores`
3. juntar `chaves` intercalando com vírgulas
4. juntar `valores` intercalando com vírgulas

   ```
   var chaves = [];
   var valores = [];
   var o = { "InputFile" : "PER_02.inp", "RunTime" : 1492167103, /* ignorando o resto por brevidade de escrita e melhor leitura */ };
   for (var chave in o) {
       chaves.push(chave);

       // se valor for string, por apóstrofos antes e depois da string
       if (typeof o[chave] === 'string') {
           valores.push("'" + o[chave] + "'");
       } else {
           valores.push(o[chave]);
       }
   }

   var insert = "INSERT INTO tabela (" + chaves.join(',') + ") VALUES (" + valores.join(',') + ")";
   ```