# Importar arquivo json para um banco de dados MySQL?

Tags: mysql, banco-de-dados, json, importação

Bem estou começado no estudo de banco de dados e me deparei com a seguinte situação tenho este arquivo json com os seguintes dados:

```
[{"nome":"José","ddd":27,"telefone":21239990,"cpf":"11111111111","sabe_programar":true},{"nome":"João","ddd":27,"telefone":21239990,"cpf":"22222222222","sabe_programar":false},{"nome":"Maria","ddd":27,"telefone":21239990,"cpf":"22222222222","sabe_programar":true},{"nome":"Antônio","ddd":27,"telefone":21239990,"cpf":"22222222222","sabe_programar":false}]
```

Bem eu já consegui passar ele para o php, com esse código:

```
<?php
$arquivo = file_get_contents('pessoas.json');
$json = json_decode($arquivo);
foreach($json as $registro):
    echo 'nome: ' . $registro->nome . ' - ddd: ' . $registro->ddd . ' - telefone: ' . $registro->telefone . ' - cpf '. $registro->cpf . ' - sabe_programar' . $registro->sabe_programar . '<br>';
endforeach;
```

Minha duvida é como faço agora para importar esses dados para um banco MySQL?(Já criei um banco, e uma tabela)

Comment: Tipo isso guardando as proporções de cada linguagem? https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/236529/64969

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Olá!
Então, faz o seguinte, transforma o Json para array e joga os dados de cada tabela para um array separado:

```
$meu_array = json_decode($var_do_jason, true);
$n = $meu_array["nome"];
$c = $meu_array["cpf"];
$r = $meu_array["rg"];
```

Depois usa um for para inserir os elementos na base:

```
for(i=0;$meu_array>i;i++){
$nome = $n[i];
$cpf = $c[i];
$rg = $r[i];
            mysql_query("INSERT INTO tabela (nome, cpf, rpg) VALUES('$nome', '$cpf', '$rg'"));

        }
```

Comment: E como eu me conecto ao banco?

Comment: Nesse caso, você tem que estudar mais sobre PHP e Mysql(até pra evitar sql injection etc).
Sugiro esses dois: http://www.devmedia.com.br/php-pdo-como-se-conectar-ao-banco-de-dados/37211

http://rberaldo.com.br/pdo-mysql/