# Converter dados em XML para SQL Insert

Tags: xml, parser

eu tenho uma arquivo com alguns dados no formato de XML exemplo:

```
<Row>
    <Data>BARRA DIRECAO AXIAL REGULAVEL</Data>
    <Data>000216</Data>
    <Data>FORD - EXPLORER  95/    RANGER  98/</Data>
   </Row>
```

eu preciso pegar estes dados massivos e converter para um modelo de SQL INSERT exemplo:

```
INSERT INTO produtos (title,prodid,description) VALUES ('BARRA DIRECAO AXIAL REGULAVEL','000216','FORD - EXPLORER  95/    RANGER  98/')
```

Estou fazer o parser pelo PHP

Comment: Relacionada: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/236522/64969

Comment: Isso pode ajudar [PHP SimpleXML](https://www.w3schools.com/PhP/php_xml_simplexml_get.asp)