# Importar JSON para Banco de Dados

Tags: banco-de-dados, json, postgresql, nosql

Tenho um arquivo json, e gostaria de  importá-lo para um banco de dados. 
Existe alguma maneira de automatizar esse processo?
Não há preferência por banco de dados, mas caso tivesse alguma função para PostgreSQL seria melhor.

Comment: Eu fiz isso com JS criando a consulta de inserção do SQLite: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/236529/64969

Answer (score 2):

A partir da versão 9.2 do PostgresSQL foi introduzido o tipo `JSON`, que suporta o armazenamento e manipulação de dados em formato JSON.

Você pode usar a função `pg_read_file()` para ler arquivos texto armazenados no `data_directory` do servidor a fim de automatizar a importação de dados.

Arquivo `paises.json`:

```
[
    { "nome": "Brasil",    "lingua": "Portugues", "moeda": "Real"  },
    { "nome": "Portugal",  "lingua": "Portugues", "moeda": "Euro"  },
    { "nome": "Argentina", "lingua": "Espanhol",  "moeda": "Peso Argentino"  },
    { "nome": "Mexico",    "lingua": "Espanhol",  "moeda": "Peso Mexicano"  },
    { "nome": "Franca",    "lingua": "Frances",   "moeda": "Euro"  },
    { "nome": "Alemana",   "lingua": "Alemao",    "moeda": "Euro"  },
    { "nome": "EUA",       "lingua": "Ingles",    "moeda": "Dolar"  }
]
```

Estrutura de Dados:

```
CREATE TABLE tb_pais
(
    cod INTEGER,
    info JSON
);
```

Importando Arquivo JSON:

```
INSERT INTO tb_pais VALUES ( 1, pg_read_file('/var/lib/pgsql/data/paises.json')::JSON );
```

Recupera todos os paises que usam o 'Euro' como moeda:

```
SELECT
    json.data->>'nome'
FROM
    (SELECT json_array_elements(info) AS data FROM tb_pais) AS json
WHERE
    json.data->>'moeda' = 'Euro'
```

Recupera todos os paises que falam 'Espanhol':

```
SELECT
    json.data->>'nome' AS nome
FROM
    (SELECT json_array_elements(info) AS data FROM tb_pais) AS json
WHERE
    json.data->>'lingua' = 'Espanhol';
```

Comment: Tentei rodar o comando:   INSERT INTO tb_pais VALUES (1, pg_read_file('C:\\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.6\data\models.json')::JSON);   Mas me retornou o erro:     ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type json
DETAIL:  Token "" is invalid.
CONTEXT:  JSON data, line 1: ...
********** Error **********

ERROR: invalid input syntax for type json
SQL state: 22P02
Detail: Token "" is invalid.
Context: JSON data, line 1: ...

Comment: O conteudo JSON está bem formado ?

Comment: Peguei o mesmo exemplo que você fez.

Answer (score 1):

No sql server você consegue importar, não sei como é o seu "automaticamente" (quando colocar em uma pasta? quando receber um email? quando chamar uma função?). Mas nesse link explica varias formas de como fazer para importar json para o sql server

https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/relational-databases/json/import-json-documents-into-sql-server